# Calculating probability given a Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let a probability density function of a random variable $X$ be given by

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^3 & \text {if } -1 \le x \le 1 \\
\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and I need to find the probability $P(-0.5 \le x \le 0.5)$.

So, I simply applied the integration for $f(x)$ with lower limit $= -0.5$ and upper limit $= 0.5$.

Since, $f(x)$ is an odd function (it is symmetric about the origin), the integration gives the value $0.$ However, the probability of course can't be 0 here. So, do I need to take absolute value of the integration for negative values of $x$ in special case of odd functions like this? Or am I missing something, because I never had to take care of any special cases like this while calculating probability of continuous functions until now!

Comment: probability density can't be negative.

Comment: Are you *sure* you've transcribed the PDF properly here?  I mean, it clearly isn't valid; what I'm wondering is whether the error is in the problem's construction, or your transcription of it.

Comment: The question is incorrect, as Cettt has pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $f$ cannot be probability density function (pdf): pdfs are always non-negative and integrate to $1$, i.e $\int_{\Bbb R} f(x) \; dx = 1$.
Your funtion $f$ satisfies neither of these conditions.